# Int output does not correspond given value

Tags: c++, int

My first stackoverflow post!

After entering a value for age into a declared and initialized int, 
something weird happens and the value explodes. I test my code and could not see why it happens. After rechecking I can see that it is the last peice of code that did something to my int value.

I ask the stackoverflow gods "Why".

My code here:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter your name and age\n\n";
    string first_name;
    int age(0);

    cout << age << "\n\n";  // for testing why i get a huge number for age

    cin>> first_name >> age;

    cout << age << "\n\n";  // for testing why i get a huge number for age
    cout << "Hello, " << first_name << " age " << age << '`\n';

    keep_window_open(); // window must be closed manually
    return 0;
}
```

*This seems to be the offending bit:*

```
 '`\n';
```

This is the output I would get:

```
Please enter your name and age

0

et
23
23

Hello, et age 2324586
```

Comment: What do you enter when asks for you first name and age?

Comment: "et" and then "23" - as shown in output

Comment: What I should get is:

Please enter your name and age

0

et
23
23

Hello, et age 23

Comment: Voting to close as a typo; You have a typo.  `'\`\n'` should be `'\n'`.  Notice you have a `\`` in there.

Answer (score 8):

```
'`\n'
```

That's actually two characters, not only the newline feed. Plus you use single quotation marks, these are only used for single characters since char literals are of type `const char`.

The standard says:

> The value of an integer character constant containing more than one
>   character (e.g., 'ab'), or containing a character or escape sequence
>   that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is
>   implementation-defined.

And thus the numbers after 23 : `24586` is the implementation-defined part that's causing weird output here. Use double quotes or `'\n'`.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: Implementation defined in this case is the bit representation of '`' = 0110 0000 and '\n' = 0000 1010 into 0110 0000 0000 1010 = 24586.